# How to add CheckBox at DevExpress xtraGrid

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I want to add CheckBox at DevExpress's xtraGrid column so for this what should i do

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Editor Repository Item (CheckEdit) in the grid's designer (under In-Place Editor Repository) and add it to the ColumnEdit property of the column (under Columns)

**EDIT:** Adding programmatically

```
Dim repstryItemCheckEdit As New RepositoryItemCheckEdit

GridControl.RepositoryItems.Add(repstryItemCheckEdit)

Dim chckEdtColumn As GridColumn = myGrid.Columns.AddField("Select")

With chckEdtColumn
  .VisibleIndex = myGrid.Columns.Count
End With
myGrid.Columns.Add(grsSalColumn)

myGrid.Columns("Select").ColumnEdit = repstryItemCheckEdit
```